# How to export multiple objects in one blender file into one FBX export, intact?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, .fbx

The actual blender mesh has wheels, separate from the middle cannon part.

[image: Blender Actual Mesh]
**This is the actual Mesh**.

When I export the mesh in Blender into fbx export it gets deformed.

[image: Deformed FBX Export]
**This is the FBX export, deformed**.

I selected the "Selected Objects" before FBX exporting. But it's the same.
[image: Selected Objects]
**Selected Objects**.

How do I keep them intact?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "*How do I keep them intact?*" You have to tick the option "Keep Intact". Seriously though, there is no recipe, porting processes are low fidelity and highly fallible, failures are expected. Adjust your model, check animations and armatures, then try again

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to what I should be checking in armatures and also adjust my model in what way? I am new to this so thanks for the help.